# Floating div doesn't push other div to it's right

Tags: css, html, css-float

i'm no expert when it comes to css but i'm trying to get a floating div to work. I have two div's, the top one floats left and the other div should wrap right. It seems to sort of do this. The problem is that even though it looks right, it's not actually pushing the box to the right of it. I have a jsfiddle and you'll see what i mean. i set a red border on the div called content. You'll see the content looks about right, but the dotted red line under the h1 start from the begining of the floated object instead of under the H1 title. Please help me understand. here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wCnY3/

```
<div id="subNav">box</div><div id="content">WELCOME</div>
```

Comment: just float your content div as well http://jsfiddle.net/wCnY3/4/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Target your `#content` element with an `overflow-x:hidden` property.

```
#content {
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/wCnY3/1/

By design, the `overflow:hidden` has the effect of forcing your element to behave like a square/rectangle. Since you don't have a set width/height for your element, that just means its wrapping behavior is changed.

Comment: that's awesome. worked perfectly! thanks. Just one quick question... why doesn't the <h1> touch the top of the redline. How do i get it to align up there? i tried display:inline, but that doesn't work.

Comment: @Damien - The browser is applying a default `margin` to the `<h1>` element. Use either a CSS reset, or just create an `#content h1 { margin:0; }` rule.

Comment: actually tried that, it moves it up a little, but not to the absolute top

Comment: Maybe `padding:0` then? What browser are you using?